# Export run configuration to command line?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am able to run my script in PyCharm using a run configuration but somehow it doesn't work when I try running in on the command line. Is there a way to export or see my PyCharm run configuration as a command line script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. PyCharm does not have an *out-of-the-box* functionality to export run configurations as a shell/cmd script and there is also no plugin for it at [JetBrains marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=pycharm&search=%22run%20configuration%22).

The functionality being seemingly simple isn't trivial:

1. Run configurations work across a variety of [terminals](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html#application-settings) and operating systems, so generating a script would require a different syntax for each (it's not trivial and would including launching processes).
2. The exported script would have to include OS specific authentication and [permissions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/default-permissions.html) for whatever services you are running (all the stuff you configure outside the IDE before launching PyCharm). It's not the IDE's job to take care of that.

You can [save run configurations to file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#save-as-permanent) (defaults to `<project directory>/.idea/runConfigurations`) which gives you an XML as shown below. From there it shouldn't be hard to copy-past what you need, if you want additional automation currently the only alternative is writing your own script.

```xml
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="CONFIG NAME" type="PythonConfigurationType" factoryName="Python">
    <module name="MODULE NAME" />
    <option name="INTERPRETER_OPTIONS" value="" />
    <option name="PARENT_ENVS" value="true" />
    <envs>
      <env name="PYTHONUNBUFFERED" value="1" />
    </envs>
    <option name="SDK_HOME" value="" />
    <option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY" />
    <option name="IS_MODULE_SDK" value="true" />
    <option name="ADD_CONTENT_ROOTS" value="true" />
    <option name="ADD_SOURCE_ROOTS" value="true" />
    <EXTENSION ID="PythonCoverageRunConfigurationExtension" runner="coverage.py" />
    <option name="SCRIPT_NAME" value="THE SCRIPT YOU ARE RUNNING" />
    <option name="PARAMETERS" value="A BUNCH OF PARAMS HERE" />
    <option name="SHOW_COMMAND_LINE" value="false" />
    <option name="EMULATE_TERMINAL" value="false" />
    <option name="MODULE_MODE" value="false" />
    <option name="REDIRECT_INPUT" value="false" />
    <option name="INPUT_FILE" value="" />
    <method v="2" />
  </configuration>
</component>
```